# Why isn't pattern matching working with 'rm' from bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I am cleaning up temporary files throughout each step of a long bash script. I am hoping to remove, using absolute file paths, every file with a certain prefix that is not a log file. I have tested the following from my linux command line and have successfully done exactly what I want (in the example, removing *1_missing.csv* and *1_missing.txt*, but not *1_missing.log*):

`rm /home/ubuntu/intermediate/1_missing.!(log)`

However, when I try the same in a bash script I run into issues. A shortened version of my bash script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

intermediate="/home/ubuntu/intermediate"
out_missing="$intermediate/1_missing"

rm "$out_missing.!(log)"
```

When I run the above bash script, I receive the error:

`rm: cannot remove '/home/ubuntu/intermediate/1_missing.!(log)': No such file or directory`

So, why is Bash interpreting the same line differently from my Linux command line? I tried quoting only the variable and leaving `.!(log)` unquoted based on another thread, but ran into a syntax error.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: For that pattern to work you need `shopt -s extglob` option enabled in your script

Comment: `into a syntax error` Please post the syntax error. For `!(out)` to expand, it has to be unquoted.

Comment: Thank you both! I enabled the option @Inian suggested and left `!(out)` unquoted and it worked perfectly. I had previously tried both of these things separately to no avail.